# Margin property doesn't work

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am using a semantic-ui framework. I am trying to make a post-comments like structure. currently my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<title>Assignments</title>
    <style>
        .items {
            width: 70%;
            border: solid;
            margin: 100px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>


<div class="ui items">
  <div class="item">
    <a class="ui tiny image">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Jenny Hess</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>First Post Ever In My Life</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui comments">

  <div class="comment">
    <a class="avatar">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author">Matt</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        How artistic!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <a class="avatar">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author">Elliot Fu</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Yesterday at 12:30AM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>This has been very useful for my research. Thanks as well!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <a class="avatar">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author">Joe Henderson</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">5 days ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Dude, this is awesome. Thanks so much
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="ui reply form">
    <div class="field">
      <textarea rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ui blue labeled submit icon button">
      <i class="icon edit"></i> Add Reply
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="ui items">
  <div class="item">
    <a class="ui tiny image">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Jenny Hess</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>First Post Ever In My Life</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui comments">

  <div class="comment">
    <a class="avatar">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author">Matt</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        How artistic!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <a class="avatar">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author">Elliot Fu</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Yesterday at 12:30AM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>This has been very useful for my research. Thanks as well!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <a class="avatar">
      <img src="img_avatar3.png">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author">Joe Henderson</a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">5 days ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Dude, this is awesome. Thanks so much
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="ui reply form">
    <div class="field">
      <textarea rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ui blue labeled submit icon button">
      <i class="icon edit"></i> Add Reply
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have made *items* width 70% and margin auto but it doesn't center. Can someone suggest me why?

Answer (score 0):

Give a specific id to parent of such item and give

```
text-align: center;
```

styling to it

Let me know if you require further help

Comment: Nope. doesn't work. it only centers texts of the items not picture and the whole structure

Comment: Had you given the id to the parent div containing all those elements